# update jQuery to use with widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to upgrade a site template that uses mainly jQuery 1.08 to use 1.11, since a widget I want to connect to the subscribe form uses 1.11.

Here's the template I'm using:

http://multifour.com/projects/ray/ios/image-intro/index.html

What's weird is if I use the following code, the header is there but the form doesn't work properly:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

And if I use this code, the form works but the header disappears:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I can't use both either, because whenever I enter the second line the header disappears for some reason. What gives, can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` file located in your `scripts` directory? Also can you please provide your html?

Comment: for the first include statement do you actually have jquery in your file system? What happens when you view the output in the console... any errors? The second include WILL include jquery so the fact that your header disappears is ummm... troubling. Check the console and report back.

Comment: Ya, I've actually included the jquery file in the scripts directory and either way I thought reading it in through googleapis would include jquery anyway. The console is reading two errors, saying that $().smoothScrool and $.stellar aren't functions in a custom.js file. If you check out the source code of the template I linked to and bring up the custom.js file (line 498), it's the exact same as the one I'm using locally. Thanks for your help so far, guys.

Answer (score 0):

**For your first problem**
I checked your directory for the jQuery script and it returned a 404. Perhaps you updated it because I noticed a different jQuery version being loaded in your view source.

http://multifour.com/projects/ray/ios/image-intro/scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js

**For your second problem**

> Ya, I've actually included the jquery file in the scripts directory and either way I thought reading it in through googleapis would include jquery anyway. The console is reading two errors, saying that $().smoothScrool and $.stellar aren't functions in a custom.js file. If you check out the source code of the template I linked to and bring up the custom.js file (line 498), it's the exact same as the one I'm using locally. Thanks for your help so far, guys.

You should use some kind of Javascript Loader because your custom.js is loaded before your jQuery libraries are loaded and thats why you would be getting the error *$().smoothScrool and $.stellar aren't functions*. Maybe try the HTML5 async Javascript attribute.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp